# LazyLoad without scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading

I'm using lazyload (JS library) and it works great! I have a long page with images where I use lazyload and, if I scroll down, it works perfectly.

The problem comes when I press a button that hide some divs on the top and the page goes up, with all the images. Lazyload doesn't load the images that rise the user view.

How could I solve this? I would need something to notify lazyload "please, load the images that are now in the user area view".

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using [verlok's lazyload library](https://github.com/verlok/lazyload), it is really simple: all you need is to inform the plugin that the layout of the page has changed (or the page content has been reflowed). This can be done by calling:

```
var myLazyLoad = new LazyLoad();
// After your content has changed...
myLazyLoad.update();
```

...which will manually update the instance. In your case, you will need to invoke `myLazyLoad.update()` when the button is pressed: how that is implemented is really up to you.

See the API documentation here: https://github.com/verlok/lazyload#dynamic-content

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly! But I had to add a setInterval function, because if not, the div was not hidden yet and lazyload doesn't notice anything has changed.

Comment: @Ommadawn Yup, you will need to call that `.update()` method at the end of the call stack, because the page will take time to relayout/reflow the content :) p/s: I hope you meant `setTimeout`?